# Can't see dwm in sddm on opensuse Leap 15.2

Tags: linux, opensuse, dwm, sddm

I installed dwm on opensuse leap 15.2 and was expecting to see it in the desktop session list, though it's not there.
I see IceWM Session, Plasma,TWM, Plasma(FullWayland) and Plasma(Wayland)

Is there a way to edit SDDM to add DWM to the list?  I thought yast-alternatives, but alas I'm stuck. Thanks and Cheers

Also I see the /etc/suckless/dwm
as well /usr/bin/dwm is the binanry.